# How to add host ip in apache log filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, logging, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I'm using AWS EC2 and I want to centralized apache2 logs (in EFS). I'd like to create logs file with names like this:

```
/var/log/apache2/172.31.23.54-access.log
/var/log/apache2/172.31.23.75-access.log
```

How can I manage such thing?

Answer (score 2):

As EFS is itself a service My First Question is do you already have a EFS in that same region where you have launched EC2 if not please first setup and EFS and once your done with the setup of the EFS please mount it on your EC2 instance using "amazon-efs-utils"

Please follow this Official Documentation for this :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/getting-started.html

Follow step 2 and 3 .

Once you are done with the above setup please create the link between your /var/log/apache2/172.31.23.54-access.log and at a folder in EFS .

Eg : ln /path/to/source /path/to/link (Run this command )

ln /var/log/apache2/access.log /mnt/efs/172.31.23.54-access.log

this is the simplest way to achieve this .

Or you can change the logs configuration directly to the EFS . please let me know if this is what you want to do? I can help with options as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think to question was not clear enough. EFS is already configured! The only thing I need is to create logs with the host ip in the filename. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try this creating a hard link :   ln /var/log/apache2/access.log /mnt/efs/172.31.23.54-access.log

Comment: the reason that I am not suggesting any automate scripting for this is because the  Host IP is not a variable I mean we don.t  change is so frequently as this is the Default AWS VPC IP I would suggest use above command and it will create a log file with this name 72.31.23.54-access.log and start writing you access.log of apache same you can do for other Apache2 as well.

Comment: I can't hardlink it because I don't know the host IP's. I want to group logs in a single dir on EFS by host IP (EC2 private IP for example, which can easily be accessed from shell)